# Django 1.4: Custom field and lookup override

Tags: python, django

---

**Notice**: I'm currently using Django-1.4 and can not upgrade to 1.7, because of production environment related constraints.

---

I have a written a custom field, `JsonListField`. Basically it's a TextField that `json.loads` its value when reading from DB and `json.dumps` it when writing. It allows me to directly manipulate a python list of simple objects.

Now, sometimes, I'd like to query on this field. For example:

```
MyModelClass.objects.query(listfield__contains="term").all()
```

What I would like, is to match that I have exactly this value in the list.

I could do:

```
MyModelClass.objects.query(listfield__regexp=r'"term"[,\]]').all()
```

But for the user of the API, i'd like this to be less invasive: use the `contains` lookup and change it on-the-fly to a regexp.
I guess I could use the `get_db_prep_lookup` method of my custom field to generate the regexp. But I would also like this function to tell the DB to match with `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`.

I have a hunch that I could create an object implementing `as_sql()` to do so, but I'm not sure I'm on the right track, and not sure this is feasible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if there's a proper JsonListField available for Django 1.4, I would think there might be one but not a 100% certain. Regardless, writing your own is at least more fun :)

A quick Google gave me these 2 results at least:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield

---

Looking at the `get_db_prep_lookup()` method it seems that you can't easily do it with that: 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django%2Fdb%2Fmodels%2Ffields%2F__init__.py#L737-L771

```
def get_db_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value, connection,
                       prepared=False):
    """
    Returns field's value prepared for database lookup.
    """
    if not prepared:
        value = self.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
        prepared = True
    if hasattr(value, 'get_compiler'):
        value = value.get_compiler(connection=connection)
    if hasattr(value, 'as_sql') or hasattr(value, '_as_sql'):
        # If the value has a relabeled_clone method it means the
        # value will be handled later on.
        if hasattr(value, 'relabeled_clone'):
            return value
        if hasattr(value, 'as_sql'):
            sql, params = value.as_sql()
        else:
            sql, params = value._as_sql(connection=connection)
        return QueryWrapper(('(%s)' % sql), params)

    if lookup_type in ('search', 'regex', 'iregex', 'contains',
                       'icontains', 'iexact', 'startswith', 'endswith',
                       'istartswith', 'iendswith'):
        return [value]
    elif lookup_type in ('exact', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte'):
        return [self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection,
                                       prepared=prepared)]
    elif lookup_type in ('range', 'in'):
        return [self.get_db_prep_value(v, connection=connection,
                                       prepared=prepared) for v in value]
    elif lookup_type == 'isnull':
        return []
    else:
        return [value]
```

While changing the `as_sql` for the value might work, looking at the code slightly further tells me that it probably won't.

Your best guess (it's something I've done in the past and which worked just fine for me since 0.95) is to overwrite the `Manager` and let it return a custom `QuerySet` which modifies the `_filter_or_exclude()` method and rewrites the queries before they're being sent.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know how to tell django to use regexp function instead of  the LIKE of 'contains'.

Comment: @OlivierH: you're completely right... my bad. I'll do a bit more research, give me a few minutes :)

Comment: @OlivierH: it seems the best way for sub-1.7 is still to overwrite the Manager and the QuerySet with that.

Comment: Great idea to use _filter_or_exclude(). I did not know of that. Seems indeed to be the way to go. I'll update the thread as soon as I have given this a try.